# Как объединить три пути и заполнить их градиентом

Tags: css, html5, svg, path, градиент

Я создал три `path`

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 10 100 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
  <path d="M 10 90 C 40 00, 65 00, 95 70 S 150 140, 180 70" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/> 
  <path d="M250 75 L180 120 L180 30 Z" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Как я могу объединить пути и заполнить их градиентом?

Создал [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/465wmnjx/14/) для этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to merge three paths and fill with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56682346/7394871) от участника  [@Stücke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5696601/st%c3%bccke).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56682346/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы объединить три пути, вы объединяете атрибуты `d` в один.

Однако в этом случае обе кривые нарисованы в одном и том же направлении, поэтому я изменил одну из них и заменил начальную команду `M` на линию `L`.

Надеюсь, это то, что вам нужно.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="lg">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(120,100%,30%)"></stop>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(320,100%,50%)"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
  <path d="M 10 100 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80
           L180,70C150,140 125,140 95,70C65,00 40,00 10,90
           M250 75 L180 120 L180 30 Z" stroke="black" fill="url(#lg)"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to merge three paths and fill with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56682534/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>